# How to Disable diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 for opensshd

Tags: linux, ssh, security

This sounds like it should be an easy process, especially for those looking at [How To Disable diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 for SSH 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/758673/how-to-disable-diffie-hellman-group1-sha1-for-ssh), yet somehow it is not.

From my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, I have:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```

`ssh -T | grep kex` shows that it is taking effect:

```
gssapikexalgorithms gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```

Yet, `ssh -v` is showing that it is still offering `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1` among others that I didn't ask for (note this is still a smaller list than if I didn't have the kex line in):

```
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

I am allowed to add it as a third option, but I cannot prepend a `-` to remove it in this mode (as anx points out below mixing in this way is now allowed, but it does show I did restart):

```
Unsupported KEX algorithm "-diffie-hellman-group14-sha1"
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 133: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,-diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'.
```

What do you have to do to get only the algorithms I list be the only ones actually offered, and specifically disable diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b FIPS  26 Feb 2019

Comment: @anx: Thank you for your suggestions.  I did restart sshd--many times and ran  sshd on alternate ports as well and saw definite signs (like mixing absolute and relative specifications of algorithms as you point out) that sshd was reading what I was writing.  I'll fix the sshd-T typo.